# combine redundant row items in r

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, summarize, mutate

I have a dataset with the the names of many different plant species (column `MTmatch`), some of which appear repeatedly. Each of these has a column (`ReadSum`) with a sum associated with it (as well as many other pieces of information). How do I combine/aggregate all of the redundant plant species and sum the associated `ReadSum` with each, while leaving the non-redundant rows alone?

I would like to take a dataset like this, and either have it transformed so that each sample has the aggregate of the combined rows, or at least an additional column showing the sum of the `ReadSum` column for the combined redundant species. Sorry if this is confusing, I'm not sure how to ask this question.

I have been messing about with dplyr, using `group_by()` and `summarise()`, but that seems to be summarizing across the whole column rather than just the new group.

```
structure(list(ESVID = c("ESV_000090", "ESV_000682", "ESV_000028", 
"ESV_000030", "ESV_000010", "ESV_000182", "ESV_000040", "ESV_000135", 
"ESV_000383"), S026401.R1 = c(0.222447727, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.029074432, 
0, 0), S026404.R1 = c(0.022583349, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.016390389, 
0.001257217, 0), S026406.R1 = c(0.360895503, 0, 0, 0.00814677, 
0, 0, 0.01513888, 0, 0.00115466)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
> dput(samp5[1:9])
structure(list(ESVID = c("ESV_000090", "ESV_000682", "ESV_000028", 
"ESV_000030", "ESV_000010", "ESV_000182", "ESV_000040", "ESV_000135", 
"ESV_000383"), S026401.R1 = c(0.222447727, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.029074432, 
0, 0), S026404.R1 = c(0.022583349, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.016390389, 
0.001257217, 0), S026406.R1 = c(0.360895503, 0, 0, 0.00814677, 
0, 0, 0.01513888, 0, 0.00115466), S026409.R1 = c(0.221175955, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.005146173, 0, 0), S026412.R1 = c(0.026058888, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), MAX = c(0.400577608, 0.009933177, 0.124412855, 
0.00814677, 0.009824944, 0.086475106, 0.154850408, 0.015593835, 
0.008340888), ReadSum = c(3.54892343, 0.012059346, 0.203303936, 
0.021075546, 0.009824944, 0.128007863, 0.859687787, 0.068159534, 
0.050266853), SPECIES = c("Abies ", "Abies ", "Acer", "Alnus", 
"Berberis", "Betula ", "Boykinia", "Boykinia", "Boykinia")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We cannot read data into R from images. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(yourdata)`, if that is not too large.

Comment: thank you! i'm not quite sure how everyone else gets it to look like neat tibbles, but i did dput

Comment: Glad you solved your problem @salix7. Thanks for updating your question with the example data; there are some other good hints for making 'good' question on stackoverflow at [how to make a great r reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do either of these approached produce your intended outcome?

Data:

```r
df <- structure(list(ESVID = c("ESV_000090", "ESV_000682", "ESV_000028", 
                         "ESV_000030", "ESV_000010", "ESV_000182", "ESV_000040", "ESV_000135", 
                         "ESV_000383"), S026401.R1 = c(0.222447727, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.029074432, 
                                                       0, 0), S026404.R1 = c(0.022583349, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.016390389, 
                                                                             0.001257217, 0), S026406.R1 = c(0.360895503, 0, 0, 0.00814677, 
                                                                                                             0, 0, 0.01513888, 0, 0.00115466), S026409.R1 = c(0.221175955, 
                                                                                                                                                              0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.005146173, 0, 0), S026412.R1 = c(0.026058888, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), MAX = c(0.400577608, 0.009933177, 0.124412855, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.00814677, 0.009824944, 0.086475106, 0.154850408, 0.015593835, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.008340888), ReadSum = c(3.54892343, 0.012059346, 0.203303936, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0.021075546, 0.009824944, 0.128007863, 0.859687787, 0.068159534, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0.050266853), SPECIES = c("Abies ", "Abies ", "Acer", "Alnus", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "Berberis", "Betula ", "Boykinia", "Boykinia", "Boykinia")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Create a new column "combined_ReadSum" (2nd col) which is the sum of "ReadSum" for each "SPECIES":

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(SPECIES) %>%
  summarise(combined_ReadSum = sum(ReadSum)) %>%
  left_join(df, by = "SPECIES")
#> # A tibble: 9 × 10
#>   SPECIES  combi…¹ ESVID S0264…² S0264…³ S0264…⁴ S0264…⁵ S0264…⁶     MAX ReadSum
#>   <chr>      <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 "Abies " 3.56    ESV_…  0.222  0.0226  0.361   0.221    0.0261 0.401   3.55   
#> 2 "Abies " 3.56    ESV_…  0      0       0       0        0      0.00993 0.0121 
#> 3 "Acer"   0.203   ESV_…  0      0       0       0        0      0.124   0.203  
#> 4 "Alnus"  0.0211  ESV_…  0      0       0.00815 0        0      0.00815 0.0211 
#> 5 "Berber… 0.00982 ESV_…  0      0       0       0        0      0.00982 0.00982
#> 6 "Betula… 0.128   ESV_…  0      0       0       0        0      0.0865  0.128  
#> 7 "Boykin… 0.978   ESV_…  0.0291 0.0164  0.0151  0.00515  0      0.155   0.860  
#> 8 "Boykin… 0.978   ESV_…  0      0.00126 0       0        0      0.0156  0.0682 
#> 9 "Boykin… 0.978   ESV_…  0      0       0.00115 0        0      0.00834 0.0503 
#> # … with abbreviated variable names ¹​combined_ReadSum, ²​S026401.R1,
#> #   ³​S026404.R1, ⁴​S026406.R1, ⁵​S026409.R1, ⁶​S026412.R1
```

Or, summarise columns by summing the values for each unique species:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(SPECIES) %>%
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 8
#>   SPECIES    S026401.R1 S026404.R1 S026406.R1 S026409.R1 S0264…¹     MAX ReadSum
#>   <chr>           <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 "Abies "       0.222      0.0226    0.361      0.221    0.0261 0.411   3.56   
#> 2 "Acer"         0          0         0          0        0      0.124   0.203  
#> 3 "Alnus"        0          0         0.00815    0        0      0.00815 0.0211 
#> 4 "Berberis"     0          0         0          0        0      0.00982 0.00982
#> 5 "Betula "      0          0         0          0        0      0.0865  0.128  
#> 6 "Boykinia"     0.0291     0.0176    0.0163     0.00515  0      0.179   0.978  
#> # … with abbreviated variable name ¹​S026412.R1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>